# How to rewrite a given greedy regex pattern?

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, crash, pattern-matching

I have two regex pattern, which I am using in vc++ program for my input string matching. These two pattern match is causing heap allocation failure.. so I wanna rewrite them. I am using regex_search() api call.

Please let me know how can I rewrite them so that they don't become greedy and hence avoid the crash.

```
(\%3E)(.)*(\%3C) 

>.*</?(\w|\s)*\b(script|applet)\b
```

Code:

```
cmatch regexMatch;  
regex_search(pbuf, regexMatch, regex(iter.second, regex_constants::icase), regex_constants::match_any);
```

Input Buffer:
`STATE[2]=TX&SHIPTOPHONE[10]=1111111111&SUBMIT=Continue+for+xxxxxxxxx+xxxx+%3EIGT&DISCOUNT[4]=0.00&_PRODUCTCODE[1]=0&TEMPLATE[9]=xxxxxxxxx&METHOD[2]=xx&VENDOR[9]=xxxxxxxxx&SHIPTOFIRSTNAME[6]=xxxxxx&SHIPTOEMAIL[18]=xxxxxxxx@yahoo.com&PARTNER[8]=xxxxxxxx&SHIPTOSTATE[2]=xx&DUTYAMT[4]=0.00&CITY[10]=xxxxxxxxxx&COUNTRYCODE[2]=XX&DESCRIPTION[4]=aepn&TRXTYPE[1]=S&PHONENUM[10]=1111111111&USER2[10]=22.2.22.22&FREIGHTAMT[4]=0.00&_HOSTEDCODE[1]=1&PWD[28]=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXSHIPTOCITY[10]=xxxxxxxxxx&_PAYMENTCODE[1]=1&LASTNAME[8]=xxxxxxxx&TENDER[1]=C&SHIPTOZIP[5]=80000&USER[14]=xxxxxxxxxXXXXX&AMT[5]=10.05&EXECUTOR[12]=xxxxxxxxxXXX&ZIP[5]=80000&EXPDATE[4]=0101&TAXAMT[4]=0.00&COUNTRY[2]=US&PLAN[4]=teen&CURRENCY[3]=USD`

Thanks !! Puneet

Comment: Change `*` to `*?` to make it non-greedy.

Comment: Are you sure you want `(.)*` and not `(.*)`. With `(.)*`, you only capture the first character, not the whole block of text.

Comment: If there are multiple ways for the regex to match (for example, `%3Exxx%3Cxxx%3C`) does it matter if it finds a different match?

Comment: @Barmar we want `(.)*` and not `(.*)`. Also, with a change from `*` to `*?` it still crashes...

Comment: Post the code and some sample input.

Comment: @Barmar Please see the code and the input buffer. I updated the question

Comment: Try `(%3E)(.*?)(%3C)` and `>.*?</?[\w\s]*\b(script|applet)\b` (do not forget to use double escapes in non-raw string literals and single escapes in raw string literals)

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew the first pattern worked. Thanks.
Can you give me a sample input buffer to test the second pattern? I tried `><script>` and `></script>` and `</script>` but its not matching the pattern.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/DZznfZ/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-vamp the parts where you define a quantified capturing group with single char pattern alternations (i.e. `(.)*` -> `(.*)` and `(\w|\s)*` -> `[\w\s]*`), and use lazy matching (`.*` -> `.*?`) in case you need to get the match up to the leftmost occurrence of subsequent patterns.

Use

```
(%3E)(.*?)(%3C)
```

and

```
>.*?</?[\w\s]*\b(script|applet)\b
```

Do not forget to use double escapes in non-raw string literals and single escapes in raw string literals.